# Notation in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I have seen the following written:

$\int_{I}f\left(x\right)\mu\left(dx\right)$.

Without the $\mu$, I think it reduces to the standard Riemann integral but what does $\mu\left(dx\right)$ mean?

Comment: I guess it might mean the Lebesgue measure.  However, I have only seen either $\mathrm d\mu$ or $\mathrm dx$ (the latter specifically denoting the Lebesgue measure on the real line).

Comment: Does that mean I just integrate $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure? Would it make sense to consider $\mu$ as a function of $dz$ (e.g. $\mu\left(dx\right)=x^2dx$) and then integrate that (multiplied by $f\left(x\right)$ by taking the Riemann integral?

Comment: I don't think $\mu(\mathrm dx)$ would literally make sense if you consider it as a function of $\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Can you provide any context?

Comment: Unfortunately that is all I know, but your comments have been helpful.

Comment: For what its worth, I've never seen that notation in any literature. And as @Vim pointed out, the notation makes little sense.

Comment: I have seen this notation a million times in all kinds of literature.  It simply denotes the integral with respect to the (arbitrary) measure $\mu $. You should interpret it as "the measure of a small change in $ x $  is evaluated by $ \mu $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation makes a bit more sense when we consider a function of more than one variable to integrate with respect to. For example, let $\mu$ be function of two variables such that when we fix $x$, $\mu(x,\cdot)$ is a measure. Then we can write $\int_X f(t) \mu(x,dt)$ to emphasize that $\mu$ is a measure with respect to the second coordinate.